# Add Property View to another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Basically i am using a segue to display a modal ViewController.

I want to the modal ViewController to display a custom subclass of `UIView` which i have declared as a **strong** property in my main ViewController like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) myView *theView;
```

in `prepareForSegue:sender:` i adjust the custom `UIView`s frame and add it to the modal ViewController:

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryBoardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UIViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    [self.theView setFrame:destination.view.bounds];
    [destination.view addSubview:self.theView];
}
```

Aside from the View still being the wrong size, only works the first time i invoke it. The second time it will crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the

```
[destination.view addSubview:self.theView];
```

line.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to pass a view from one controller to another? It's not a common practice to pass views that way. Is the view being used in the first controller?

Comment: Yeah i know, i the time you answered i figured that it is a bad idea anyway a changed the way i did it. Basically i had a DataSource in my MainView Controller which automatically updates the Custom View on CoreData changes(i use that feature mainly for the iPad version where the custom View is visible all the time). On the iPhone i tried to make use of that feature so that the ViewController im presenting modally is loaded faster because the customView it should present is already ready for presentation. Now im scrapping this and just creating the custom View on the fly.

Comment: Still it would be nice to know why exactly this isn't working! I guess it has something to do with ARC?!